# Hibernate ogm infinispan @manytoone bidirectional issue on wildfly 17

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate-ogm, infinispan-9, wildfly-17

I face an issue when i use infinispan ogm with a file-store configuration.
My issue is the following. 
I have deployed on wildfly 17 a very little REST application able to persist and read very simple data model. The data model is composed of a biderectional manytoOne association.

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "foo")
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addBar(String name) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setName("Bar_"+name);
        String id_foo = "Foo_" + name + "_id";
        String id_bar = "Bar_" + id_foo;
        bar.setId(id_bar);
        bars.add(bar);
        bar.setFoo(this);

   //getter and setter
}
@Entity(name = "Bar")
public class Bar {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Foo foo;

    }

}

public class FooBarService {

    @Inject
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    String persisitFoo(String name) {


        Foo foo = new Foo();
        String id_foo = "Foo_" + name + "_id";
        foo.setId(id_foo);
        foo.setName("Foo_"+name);

        //add a bar
        foo.addBar(name);

        entityManager.persist(foo);
        entityManager.flush();

        Foo result = entityManager.find(Foo.class, id_foo);
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Transactional
    String getBar(String name) {

        String id_foo = "Foo_" + name + "_id";
        String id_bar = "Bar_" + id_foo;

        // build the EntityManagerFactory as you would build in in Hibernate ORM

        Bar result = entityManager.find(Bar.class, id_bar);
        entityManager.flush();

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Transactional
    String getFoo(String name) {


        String id_foo = "Foo_" + name + "_id";

        // build the EntityManagerFactory as you would build in in Hibernate ORM

        Foo result = entityManager.find(Foo.class, id_foo);
        entityManager.flush();

        return result.toString();
    }
```

When I persist a Foo (composed of one Bar) i can getFoo and the Foo object contains a Bar, but when i restart the rest application **when I get Foo object I lose the Bar assocation**. When i get the Bar object the association with Foo object is present.
Here is the configuration of my application
presistence.properties (I use a producer to programaticaly build an entityManager based on HibernateOgmPersistence). **It seems that the bidirectional works only in one way**

```
####################################################################
# Configure hibernate OGM based on infinispan provider
####################################################################
hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider=infinispan_embedded

#############################################
#  CACHE_PER_KIND: Three caches will be used: 
#  1) one cache for all entities
#  2) one cache for all associations 
#  3) one cache for all id sources
##############################################
hibernate.ogm.datastore.keyvalue.cache_mapping=CACHE_PER_KIND
########################################################################
# Should point to the resource name of an Infinispan configuration file.
# The referenced Infinispan configuration should define a CacheStore
# for entities, associations adn id sources 
#########################################################################
hibernate.ogm.infinispan.configuration_resource_name=ems-model-infinispan.xml
```

here is the infinispan configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 ~ Hibernate OGM, Domain model persistence for NoSQL datastores
 ~
 ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later
 ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
  -->
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:9.4 http://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-9.4.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:9.4">


    <jgroups>
        <!-- This is the default JGroups stack -->
         <stack-file name="ems-jgroups" path="ems-jgroups-udp.xml"/>
    </jgroups>

    <cache-container name="ems-model" default-cache="DEFAULT" statistics="false" shutdown-hook="DONT_REGISTER">

        <transport stack="ems-jgroups"  cluster="EMS"/>
        <jmx duplicate-domains="true"/>

        <!-- ***************************************************************** -->
        <!--     Default cache (no longer used as template, since infinispan 9 -->
        <!-- ***************************************************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="DEFAULT" mode="SYNC" statistics="false" statistics-available="false">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <!--  transaction mode="BATCH" locking="PESSIMISTIC" transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.WildflyTransactionManagerLookup"/ -->
            <transaction mode="BATCH" locking="PESSIMISTIC"/>
            <expiration interval="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store fetch-state="true" preload="true" path="/root/infinispan"/>
            </persistence>
            <state-transfer timeout="480000"/>
        </replicated-cache>

        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <!--     Cache to store the OGM entities     -->
        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="ENTITIES" mode="SYNC" statistics="false" statistics-available="false">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH" locking="PESSIMISTIC"/>
            <expiration interval="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store fetch-state="true" preload="true" path="/root/infinispan"/>
            </persistence>
            <state-transfer timeout="480000"/>
        </replicated-cache>

        <!-- *********************************************** -->
        <!--   Cache to store the relations across entities  -->
        <!-- *********************************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="ASSOCIATIONS" mode="SYNC" statistics="false" statistics-available="false">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH" locking="PESSIMISTIC"/>
            <expiration interval="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store fetch-state="true" preload="true" path="/root/infinispan"/>
            </persistence>
            <state-transfer timeout="480000"/>
        </replicated-cache>

        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <!--   Cache to store identifiers  -->
        <!-- ***************************** -->
        <replicated-cache name="IDENTIFIERS" mode="SYNC" statistics="false" statistics-available="false">
            <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
            <transaction mode="BATCH" locking="PESSIMISTIC"/>
            <expiration interval="-1"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store fetch-state="true" preload="true" path="/root/infinispan"/>
            </persistence>
            <state-transfer timeout="480000"/>
        </replicated-cache>

    </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

the used verion of hibernate ogm is

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.4.1.Final</version> 
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**Note That**
I have changed the provider by using mongodb and it's worked perfectly.

```
hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider=mongodb
hibernate.ogm.datastore.host:127.0.0.1:27017
hibernate.ogm.datastore.database:ems
hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database:true
```

Comment: When creating the association, are you correctly updating both sides of the relation?

Comment: When i persist the Foo object the following annotaion cascade = CascadeType.ALL should update the object bar

Comment: 1) I start rest application i persist Foo with a bar 
2) I get the Foo all is ok (i have a Bar)
3) I stop and restart application
4) I can get the Foo but a lose the Bar

Comment: I the the issue is probably concerning the file-store infinispan configuration (because it is work with mongodb)

Comment: With hibernate ogm **5.1.0.Final** it works perfectely but dosn't work with **5.4.1.Final**